# How to send data from android to mysql?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to send data from android to php file which is adding data to mysql database using POST method, i have no idea how i coult bite this.. any help?

I already connected with http by method post.. and no clue what now...

```
public URL makeUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

public static void HttpConnect(URL url) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                //to do
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }

    }
```

PHP FILE with adding by POST method.

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    require 'connect.php';
    create();
}

function create(){
    global $connect;

    $name = $_POST["nazwa"];
    $ingredients = $_POST["skladniki"];
    $price = $_POST["cena"];
    $type = $_POST["typ"];
    $photo = $_POST["zdjecie"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO dania('nazwa','skladniki','cena','typ','zdjecie') VALUES ('$name','$ingredients','$price','$type','$photo');";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}



?>
```

Comment: this is temporary i want to add come content first to check if all together works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Uri.Builder to attach POST payloads and write it on OutputStream,

In Below code, replace YOUR_VALUE1,YOUR_VALUE2,YOUR_VALUE3,YOUR_VALUE4,YOUR_VALUE5 to suitable values which you like to POST it to server.

Also i would recommend this block of code wrapped inside AsyncTask.

Eg.

```
public static void HttpConnect(URL url) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.appendQueryParameter("nazwa",YOUR_VALUE1);
            builder.appendQueryParameter("skladniki",YOUR_VALUE2);
            builder.appendQueryParameter("cena",YOUR_VALUE3);
            builder.appendQueryParameter("typ",YOUR_VALUE4);
            builder.appendQueryParameter("zdjecie",YOUR_VALUE5);

            String urlQuery = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTf-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(urlQuery);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));

            String line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // your json response output is here
            Log.d("RESULT",stringBuilder.toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

For the Complete example, i have written about AsyncTask in my [blog](https://vasudevkumaran.com/voldblog/content/index/category/android/topic/webservice_post)